# Angularjs - General structure (route angular)

Tags: angularjs

I am new in angular,  want to do the next web site in angular

This would be the main structure:

[image]

- The snippet1 is always fixed
- The snippet3 is the dynamic part

If i click in the link1 or link2 of the snippet2,load would be in the snippet3 ().

Now I expose my doubt:

If i click in icons the snippet1, the load web page would be in snippet4.

Like the image:

[image]

Error, when i try install "express cors":

[image]

How could do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Prerequisites:

- Node.js

### Step #1: Setup a new project directory

- app.js
- css (folder)

  - main.css
  - snip3.css
  - snip4.css
- ctrl (folder)

  - snip3Ctrl.js
  - snip4Ctrl.js
- index.html
- nodeServer.js
- partials (folder)

  - snip3.html
  - snip4.html

### Step #2: Install npm packages

From your project directory, run:

`npm install express cors`

### Step #3: Copy and paste code

#### app.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/snip3.html',
      controller: 'snip3Ctrl'
    })
    .when('/snip3', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/snip3.html',
      controller: 'snip3Ctrl'
    })
    .when('/snip4', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/snip4.html',
      controller: 'snip4Ctrl'
    })
    .otherwise({ template: '<h1>Not Found</h1>' });
});
app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
  delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
}]);
```

#### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Angular Routing Demo</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css">
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
    <script src="ctrl/snip3Ctrl.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/snip3.css" />
    <script src="ctrl/snip4Ctrl.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/snip4.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container" style="height: 100%;">
      <nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-responsive">
        <!-- snippet #1 here -->
      </nav>
      <div style="height: 200px;"></div>
      <ng-view></ng-view>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### nodeServer.js

```
var express = require('express'), cors = require('cors'), app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use("/", express.static(__dirname));

app.listen(8080, function(){
  console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port', 8080);
});
```

#### snip3Ctrl.js

```
angular.module('app').controller('snip3Ctrl', function($scope, $http) {

});
```

#### snip4Ctrl.js

```
angular.module('app').controller('snip4Ctrl', function($scope, $http) {

});
```

### Step #4: Run the node server

From your project directory, run:

`node nodeServer.js`

### Done!

It will serve your page to localhost:8080 by default. In case I forgot anything, post a comment and I will try to update the answer.

Comment: I have a project under to node running in my Pc, in this URL:
C:\Users\Documents\MY_PROJECT\app\WebMain\. I have created other project called "WebTest" and i have introduced the structure that you propused to me.

Comment: But when I install the package "express cors" it fails, i  am installing the package in this URL (from the command line):
C:\Users\Documents\MY_PROJECT\,thanks for  your help

Comment: Do you have [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) from the prerequisites? [NPM (Node Package Manager)](https://www.npmjs.com/) installs automatically as the default package manager of Node.js. I would try the stable version 5.10.0. You will know if NPM installs if running ```npm -version``` returns with a version number. You will know ```npm install express cors``` works if it creates a new NODE_MODULES folder. This install command should be installed in the same directory as the other folders and files from step #2.

Comment: I just saw your updated post. Try to install them one at a time maybe? ```npm install express``` then ```npm install cors```. If that doesn't work, try ```npm iniit``` to create a package.json file, add the two dependencies, then run ```npm install```.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ui-router for the routes.
In the main index.html, add the header navbar, and let the links manipulate the state of the application.

```
<body ng-controller="AppController">
  <header>
    <a ui-sref="Snippet4"></a>
  </header>
  <div ui-view></div>
</body>
```

That's the starting point for the html.