# Angular and Express routing with html5mode enabled

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, angular-ui-router

So my question is: how could I make angular and express routing work together with html5mode enabled? When I change state from '/' to my admins state I get list of all admins and everything is fine until I refresh my page. Then I get only json result of admins but my view disappears. I copied only peace of code which is relevant - to make it shorter, there is no syntax errors.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

My file structure:

```
+-- client
|   app
|       admin.config.js
|       admin.js
|       admin.module.js
|   assets
|   views
|       admin
|           admin-edit.ejs
|           admin-list.ejs
|   lib
|       bower components
+-- server
|   routes
|       index.js
|       admins.js
|   models
|       Admin.js
|   config
|       dbconfig.js
|   server.js
```

In my Angular module.config I have:

```
function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('admins', {
            url        : '/admins',
            templateUrl: '/views/admin/admin-list.ejs',
            controller : 'AdminController',
            resolve    : {
                loginRequired: loginRequired,
                getAdminList : getAdminList
            }
        });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/admins');
```

My server.js file looks like:

```
/* Routes */
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var auth   = require('./routes/auth');
var users  = require('./routes/users');
var admins = require('./routes/admins');


var app = express();


/*************************************
 App initialization
 **************************************/

/* Auto increment mongoose plugin */
autoIncrement.initialize(connection);

/* Auth secret code*/
app.set('superSecret', dbconfig.SECRET);


/* View engine setup */
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '../client/views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');


// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static('client'));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/auth', auth);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/admins', admins);
```

My index route looks like:

```
var express = require('express');
var router  = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index');
});


module.exports = router;
```

I tried adding this into my server.js

```
app.get('*', function (req, res){
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/client/index.ejs'));
});
```

and in this case when I refresh page while my url is /admins I get downloaded index page.

I also tried adding in my index.js route

```
router.get('*', function (req, res) {
   res.render('index');
})
```

and as result of adding this is endless loop in my admins list.

In my index.ejs I have

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<base href="/">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time I found solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21660454/anguarjs-node-js-web-server-js-remove-hashtag-from-url-and-support-it-by-ser), instead of specific pages I added asterisk (*) to every get request I made so now my auth route looks like:

```
router.route('/signup')

    /* Render index by default */
    .get(function (req, res) {
        res.render('index', {
            page: req.params.page
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a lot of code. [I want to give you this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36377576/angularjs-general-structure-route-angular/36379495#36379495). It is an answer I posted yesterday that I am proud of. It is a simple example of Angular routing in Angular 1.5. You will have to add your line about `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` because I am not using it.